# JavaScript Not Showing Date Functions

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to use a small portion of JavaScript in order to show how many days are left until New Year's Eve. However, I can't get any of it to show up on the webpage. I'll include the HTML and the library I am trying to use, if anybody can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. I was under the impression that HTML was able to understand Date() functions, but my teacher told me I would have to remove them in order to get the code working?

```
<!-- Days until New Year's Eve -->
<td id="daycell">
<!-- Add script tag and declare variables and assign values -->
<script>
    var Today = new(Date);
    var ThisDay = Today.getDate();
    var ThisMonth = Today.getMonth();
    var ThisYear = Today.getFullYear();
    var DaysLeft = NYEdays(Today);
    var MonthTxt = new Array("", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
"September", "October", "November", "December");

<!-- Add date output statement -->
document.write("Today is" + MonthTxt[ThisMonth] + " " + ThisDay + ", " + ThisYear + ".");

<!-- Add decision statement for number of days -->
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    if (DaysLeft == 0) {
        document.write("Today is New Years Eve!");
    }
    else {
        document.write("Only" + DaysLeft "days until New Years Eve!");
    }
</script>
```

Here is the library.js code:

```
function NYEDays(CheckDay) {
    var XYear=CheckDay.getFullYear();
    var XDay=new Date("December, 31, 2015");
    XDay.setFullYear(XYear);
    var DayCount=(XDay-CheckDay)/(1000*60*60*24);
    DayCount=Math.round(DayCount);
    return DayCount;
}
```

I have to use the variables Today, ThisDay, ThisMonth, ThisYear, DaysLeft, and MonthTxt as an array.

Comment: You have a few typos, including a function name different from the call (case sensitive). It's also not good practice to use document.write. Check the console for errors and you'll see where the problems are.

Comment: You have a bunch of problems, like a `<script>` tag inside another one and HTML comments inside a `<script>` tag. You also are missing a `+` in your last `document.write`. It's not clear what you're trying to do. Also, you wrote, `I was under the impression that HTML was able to understand Date() functions.` I'm not sure where you got that, but that's incorrect. `Date` is a JavaScript native object type. HTML, on the other hand, doesn't "understand" anything and doesn't do anything with JavaScript objects directly.

Comment: To be blunt: your code is a nightmare between mixed HTML and JavaScript. Please ask your teacher again until you understand what he was trying to say.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, to be honest I thought I had major issues with the code, but it turned out to be small typos that you pointed out. This is my first week doing JavaScript (have a few classes experience with C++ and Java), but your help really showed me some stuff to look out for. Thanks again. Also, we were handed a sort of "fill in the blanks" assignment so I know it looked ugly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored your code. Here's the JSFiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/vytfeq8k/

**HTML:**

```
    <!-- Used divs instead of td as td needs to be within a table -->
    <div id="curDate"></div>
    <div id="daycell"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // removed many unneeded variables
    var curDate = new(Date);
    var daysLeft = nyeDays(curDate);

    // Fixed your array, you had an empty string as the first element so it would always return the previous month in the output
    var monthTxt = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

    // Added another div instead of using document.write
    $('#curDate').text("Today is " + monthTxt[curDate.getMonth()] + " " + curDate.getDate() + ", " + curDate.getFullYear() + ".");

    // Same for this bit
    if (daysLeft != 0) {
        $('#daycell').text('Only ' + daysLeft + " days until New Years Eve");   
    } else {
        $('#daycell').text('Today is New Years Eve');
    }

    // Refactored this 
    function nyeDays(checkDay) {
        var nye = new Date("December, 31, 2015");
        var dayCount = (nye - checkDay) / (1000*60*60*24);
        return Math.round(dayCount);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! My hands were kind of tied with this assignment, we were handed the script that I posted, and only supposed to add JavaScript between the script tabs, and had to use all of the variables that they included. And for some reason we were required to have the first location of monthTxt set as "". It's our first week doing JavaScript so maybe that's why it was laid out that way, but your suggestions make a lot more sense.

Comment: Ok fair enough. The code you were given is a bit all over the place with lots of bugs, maybe your first class was how not to write Javascript =P 

Anyway, I hope you understand what I changed in your code and why.